# Unable to set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined or null reference

Tags: 2013, datatable

I am working on datatables, I am getting the following error:

Unable to set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined or null reference

Does anybody encountered the same erro?

Thanks

Comment: I often get the error when you are trying to show more/less columns that exists in the actual HTML table. Care to share your code?

Comment: Yes this was exactly the issue..Thanks for responding

Answer (score 2):

This is because the count of  element is different with count of  element

For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th> <!-- 3 ths -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td> <!-- 4 tds -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Either your table td is lower or table th is lower.

So the DataTable will make it as an error.

Comment: To restate Josua's point differently, this error is due to a mismatch of column count between the heading row and the data rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">details</td>
    <td style="display: none"></td>
    <td style="display: none"></td>
    <td style="display: none"></td>
</tr>
```

Add the required cells but hide them.